# Using Emacs as external editor of Xilinx ISE, how to change the related buffer to current buffer when click a design file?

Tags: emacs, xilinx-ise

It has been like one year or so since I started to learn Emacs, and I do like its power and flexibility as a general text editor. When I had tried its Auctex mode for LaTeX/TeX, I knew I will never go back to read which TeX editor I should use. When I had tried its Pyhon mode, I knew I will never be bothered to choose a Python editor/IDE. Well, the same feeling for the VHDL mode of Emacs.

I do not intend to implement Emacs as a whole FPGA design solution (although I tried that). Instead, I prefer to use Emacs just as an external editor (Xilinx ISE in my case) and follow the design sequence according to the ventor's specific IDE. So according to this [Editor Options](http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx10/isehelp/pn_db_editor_options.htm), I set the editor options in my ISE `{C:\Program Files (x86)\emacs\bin\emacsclient.exe} +$2 $1`. However if I use `runemacs.exe` as suggested by Xilinx, everytime I clicked a file in ISE a new Emacs will be started. With the `emacsclient.exe` it helps a bit.

1. When I clicked a file in ISE now, its corresponding buffer will be opened in Emacs. But *the buffer remains invisible and I have to `C-x b` to it by my self.*
2. Also if I clicked the error information in ISE's console, the file containing the error will be opened in the background of Emacs with the cursor in the error position.

While it is not a big deal if I compare the benefits and drawbacks brought by Emacs VHDL mode, I do like *Emacs can change the file I opened in ISE to the current buffer.* **So the question is how to set Emacs or Xilinx ISE to change Emacs's current buffer to the one I opened or clicked in ISE?**

I suppose it should be some configuration related to Emacs rather than settings in ISE (obvious there is not too much choice in ISE's options). It maybe a simple question but it's beyond my current knowledge of Emacs configuration. I really appreciate if someone here could help me on this issue. Thank you guys in advance:)

P.S. Sorry for my poor English expression. Hopefully you can understand my quesition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some configuration it's possible to tell Emacs to switch to the related buffer.  However, you might want to consider opening a new window (frame in Emacs term) when you call the editor in ISE.

The command line parameter -c tells Emacs client to open a new frame

```
{C:\Program Files (x86)\emacs\bin\emacsclient.exe} -c +$2 $1
```